# Siamese network for audio classification shows no improvement

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

So, I've been trying to create a Siamese network that compares two audio files and decides if the same speaker is in both recordings (text-independent). I use a Siamese network because I plan on turning this into an attendance taking system, and it would be hard to get a lot of data from each person.

The way my program works is by loading 5-second wav audio clips from predefined folders, and then assigning them into negative and positive pairs. The model is then trained. Problem is, the model's validation accuracy doesn't change or changes between two values (0.729 and 0.648 for example). Here are the code files of my program:

process_audio.py - used to load and process audio files.

```
import os
import librosa
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.image import resize

def process_audio(audio_data, sample_rate, target_shape=(128, 128)):
    length = len(audio_data)/sample_rate
    max_length = 5*sample_rate
    if length > 5:
        audio_data = audio_data[:max_length]

    mel_spectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=audio_data, sr=sample_rate)
    mel_spectrogram = resize(np.expand_dims(mel_spectrogram, axis=-1), target_shape)
    return mel_spectrogram

def load_and_preprocess_data(data_dir, classes, target_shape=(128, 128)):
    data = []
    labels = []
    
    for i, class_name in enumerate(classes):z
        class_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, class_name)
        for filename in os.listdir(class_dir)[:30]:
            if filename.endswith('.wav'):
                file_path = os.path.join(class_dir, filename)
                audio_data, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_path, sr=16000)
                data.append(process_audio(audio_data, sample_rate, target_shape))
                labels.append(i)

    return np.array(data), np.array(labels)

def load_and_process_single(file_path, target_shape=(128, 128)):
    audio_data, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_path, sr=16000)
    processed_audio = process_audio(audio_data, sample_rate, target_shape)
    return np.array([processed_audio])
```

preprocess_pairs.py - turns data into pairs

```
import numpy as np

def load_pairs(data, labels):
"""
arguments -\>
data : list of mel spectograms
labels : labels from 0 to number of classes
returns positive and negative pairs along with their new labels
"""
groups = \[\]
positive_pairs = \[\]
negative_pairs = \[\]

    # split data into groups by label
    for i in range(len(data)):
        try:
            groups[labels[i]].append(data[i])
        except:
            groups.insert(labels[i], [])
            groups[labels[i]].append(data[i])
    
    # loop through items in the same group and asign them as a positive pair
    for i in range(len(groups)):
        for j in range(0, len(groups[i]), 2):
            pair = (groups[i][j], groups[i][j+1])
            positive_pairs.append(pair)
    
    # loop through items of different groups and asign negative pairs
    compared = []
    for i in range(0, min(map(len, groups))-1):
        for j in range(len(groups)):
            for x in range(len(groups)):
                if x == j or j in compared:
                    break
    
                pair = (groups[j][i], groups[x][i])
                negative_pairs.append(pair)
    
        compared.append(j)
    
    # get rid of the temporary variable
    del(compared)
    
    # comvert to ndarray
    positive_pairs = np.array(positive_pairs)
    negative_pairs = np.array(negative_pairs)
    # concatenate positive and negative pairs into 1
    pairs = np.concatenate((positive_pairs, negative_pairs), axis=0)
    
    # generate new labels showing difference. 1 means alike, 0 means not alike
    diffs = np.array([1]*len(positive_pairs) + [0]*len(negative_pairs))
    
    return (pairs, diffs)
```

train.py - trains the model

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.layers import \*
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import \*
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from process_audio import \*
from preprocess_pairs import \*

audio_data_shape = (128, 128)

# List of classes (also folder names)

classes = \["Ahmed Hussain", "Alasfoor", "Ali Ayyad", "Ali Jaffar", "Elyas"\]
data, labels = load_and_preprocess_data("Audio", classes, target_shape=audio_data_shape)

# Load data into pairs

pairs, diffs = load_pairs(data, labels)

# Get train and test splits

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(pairs, diffs, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)

# Create the cnn model for feature extraction

cnn_model = Sequential(\[
Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 1)),
BatchNormalization(),
Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
BatchNormalization(),
GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
Dense(64, activation='relu')
\])

# Define inputs for compared voices (can be said images as they are melspectograms)

input1 = Input(audio_data_shape, name='voice_1')
input2 = Input(audio_data_shape, name='voice_2')

# convert to feature vector using cnn model

feature_vector_1 = cnn_model(input1)
feature_vector_2 = cnn_model(input2)

# Create the main model with dropout layers to avoid overfitting

concat = Concatenate()(\[feature_vector_1, feature_vector_2\])
dropout1 = Dropout(0.5, seed=77)(concat)
dense1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(dropout1)
dropout2 = Dropout(0.5, seed=77)(dense1)
output_layer2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dropout2)

model = Model(inputs=\[input1, input2\], outputs=output_layer2)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1E-6), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=\['accuracy'\])

# Train the model with the extracted data

model.fit(x=\[x_train\[:, 0, :, :\], x_train\[:, 1, :, :\]\], y=y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=16,
validation_data=\[(\[x_test\[:, 0, :, :\], x_test\[:, 1, :, :\]\]), y_test\])\`\`\`
```

Example output (its worth noting the accuracy sometimes increases or decreases but snaps back to the value its stuck on):

```
2024-03-25 23:57:04.001297: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182\] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
C:\\Users\\NV23142\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\librosa\\core\\spectrum.py:257: UserWarning: n_fft=2048 is too large for input signal of length=1920
warnings.warn(
C:\\Users\\NV23142\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\librosa\\core\\spectrum.py:257: UserWarning: n_fft=2048 is too large for input signal of length=0
warnings.warn(
C:\\Users\\NV23142\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\librosa\\core\\spectrum.py:257: UserWarning: n_fft=2048 is too large for input signal of length=606
warnings.warn(
C:\\Users\\NV23142\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\librosa\\core\\spectrum.py:257: UserWarning: n_fft=2048 is too large for input signal of length=286
warnings.warn(
Epoch 1/20
13/13 \[==============================\] - 5s 262ms/step - loss: 0.6883 - accuracy: 0.5743 - val_loss: 0.6769 - val_accuracy: 0.7059
Epoch 2/20
13/13 \[==============================\] - 3s 239ms/step - loss: 0.6927 - accuracy: 0.5149 - val_loss: 0.6815 - val_accuracy: 0.7059
Epoch 3/20
13/13 \[==============================\] - 3s 236ms/step - loss: 0.6918 - accuracy: 0.5099 - val_loss: 0.6835 - val_accuracy: 0.7059
Epoch 4/20
13/13 \[==============================\] - 3s 237ms/step - loss: 0.6930 - accuracy: 0.5198 - val_loss: 0.6845 - val_accuracy: 0.6667
Epoch 5/20
13/13 \[==============================\] - 3s 237ms/step - loss: 0.6870 - accuracy: 0.5594 - val_loss: 0.6848 - val_accuracy: 0.6471
Epoch 6/20
13/13 \[==============================\] - 3s 236ms/step - loss: 0.6863 - accuracy: 0.5495 - val_loss: 0.6849 - val_accuracy: 0.6863
Epoch 7/20
13/13 \[==============================\] - 3s 236ms/step - loss: 0.6902 - accuracy: 0.5446 - val_loss: 0.6849 - val_accuracy: 0.7059
Epoch 8/20
13/13 \[==============================\] - 3s 245ms/step - loss: 0.6929 - accuracy: 0.5198 - val_loss: 0.6850 - val_accuracy: 0.7255
Epoch 9/20
13/13 \[==============================\] - 3s 237ms/step - loss: 0.6887 - accuracy: 0.5446 - val_loss: 0.6850 - val_accuracy: 0.7059
Epoch 10/20
13/13 \[==============================\] - 3s 239ms/step - loss: 0.6909 - accuracy: 0.5495 - val_loss: 0.6851 - val_accuracy: 0.7059
Epoch 11/20
13/13 \[==============================\] - 3s 239ms/step - loss: 0.6912 - accuracy: 0.5446 - val_loss: 0.6852 - val_accuracy: 0.7059
Epoch 12/20
5/13 \[==========\>...................\] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.6895 - accuracy: 0.5250Traceback (most recent call last):\`\`\`
```

To fix the error I tried solutions that were suggested on similar threads. These include:

1. Decreasing the learning rate (it can be noted its already 1E-6 in the code snippets).
2. Add dropout layers.
3. Decrease model complexity

I was expecting some improvement, as the other members have found these solutions helpful. But I wasn't lucky enough (or perhaps skilled enough) to produce better results. These solutions either showed no difference in results or made the results worse.

Comment: which of the three modules posted are we supposed to look at ?

Comment: Clearly train.py. The others are complimentary in the case of wanting to understand the code more deeply.